# Count Figure number by chapter level with XSL in Dita OT plugin

Tags: xslt, dita

In default DITA OT pdf plug in,  all figures are numbered by document level, which  is from figure 1 ,2, 3 to the last figure of this document.

I wish to have figure numbered by chapter level

```
In chapter 1, I have figure 1-1, 1-2, .....
In chapter 2, I have figure 2-1, 2-2, etc.
```

Each chapter can have sub chapters and each chapter xml format is like below, no matter it is chapter 1 or chapter 1.1.1.

```
 <topic id="concept_hvx_wyx_dk">
    <title>Toolbar</title>` 
        <conbody>
         <p>This section describes the usage of the toolbar.
          <fig>
         <image placement="break" href="../images/toolbar.png" id="image_gw5_dtx_dk" width="450"/>
</fig>
```

The code I used to count figure number by the document leve is below and it works OK.

```
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/table ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]" mode="table.title-number">
    <xsl:call-template name="getChapterPrefix" />
    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('enumerableByClass', 'topic/table', ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')][last()])[. &lt;&lt; current()])" />
  </xsl:template>
```

The code I copied to count figure number by chapter lever is below and it works NOK. All figures are still numbered from 1, 2 ... in document level.

Can anyone check it for me or explain it, since I am a new hand for this xsl.

```
   <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/fig ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]" mode="fig.title-number">
    <xsl:call-template name="getChapterPrefix" />    
      <xsl:value-of select="count(key('enumerableByClass', 'topic/fig', ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')][last()])&#xA;  *[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]]&#xA; [. &lt;&lt; current()])" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot!

Lisa

Comment: Try using `xsl:number` with a `from` attribute. No answer because no [mcve] was provided.

Comment: Have you tried [PDF Plugin generator](http://dita-generator.elovirta.com/#p4) and checked the code it generates? On Style page, select figure and there you can choose caption numbering to be chapter wide.

Comment: Hi jelovirt, nice to say hello to you!!  my codes is from PDF plugin generator.  1. the code for document level works nice. 2. the code for chapter level not working.  I tested them with the plugin created by the PDF plugin generator dirctly without changing.   BTW, PDF plugin generator is to DITA OT 2.4 and my DITA OT is 2.5, I don't know if this is why it doesn't work.  Thanks for helping!